# Whitespace between content and footer in Ebay listing template.

Tags: html, css

I'm designing an ebay template. However, a problem that I keep running into is that there seems to be a whitespace which I can't get rid of between the mainContainer div and the footer. I have highlighted the two divs with green and red to make the problem clear.

I want to know how I can get rid of the whitespace, and have the two divs underneath each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/4vembvLg/

Help is appreciated.

The whole code is on jsfiddle

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.footer {
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
#top-bar {
    background: url(http://demo.presthemes.com/centrikids/themes/pt_centrikids/img/bg_topbottom.png) repeat-x;
    height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: You are using `top: -400px;` to `.mainContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the top rule in the mainContainer class and  pageContainer id

```
.mainContainer {
    background-color: green;
    height: 900px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    /* top: -400px; */
    width: 100%;
}

#pageContainer {
   font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-style: normal;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0;
   position: relative;
   /* top: -267px; */
   width: 1393px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found your issue, top: -400px;

```
.mainContainer {
    background-color: green;
    height: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    /* background: #f8f8f8; */
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -400px; <----------------This Guy here
}
```

Comment: I did like you said, and then I'm getting a white space at the top, before the maincontainer.

Comment: Ok, heres what you do, removethe top: -400p like abve.  Then remove the top: 267px in #pageContainer.  Then completely remove #top-bar from your html, then set the background-image from #top-bar to #top-back.  You have an unnecessary div.